# strange error in nodejs when request promis used in for loop manner?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, promise, cheerio

I have the following web data collector:

```
function start(urls) {
  Promise.map(urls, requestPromise)
  .map((htmlPage, index) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlPage);

    $(".fixedttitle2").each(function () {
      mytxt = $(this).text();

      myarray.push(mytxt);
    });
    mainarray[urls[index]] = myarray;
  });
  fs.writeFileSync("1.json", JSON.stringify(mainarray));
}

var urls = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  urls = "https://thisurl.com/" + i.toString();

  start(urls);
}
```

Now I want to check response of each request at first, How I can check the response code at first inorder to get rid of some URLs that return 500 Error? How I can handle it?

Comment: Typo: You forgot the `https://` or `http://` at the front of the URL.

Comment: you're also calling start with a single URL ... doesn't it expect an array of URLs?

Comment: you're also calling `start` with a single URL ... doesn't it expect an array of URLs? bluebird Promise.map expects an iterable as the first argument .... so calling it with the string `https://thisurl.com/` will call **the function** `requestPromise` with `h`, then `t`, then `t`, then `p` etc ... I would imagine this is the case - why don't you add a console.log in `requestPromise` to verify (it's probably when `:` is used as the argument for that function that isn't important that you get the error)

Comment: I have no idea what you need to do, only what you have done - I don't "bluebird" so I can't post anything that will help

Comment: step 1 ... create an array of the URL's ... step 2 ... call your start function passing in the array of URL's (you do know what an Array is?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this.

- `scrape` (née `start`) processes a single URL and returns a promise of `[url, content]`, or if there's an error, `[url, null]`.
- `main` generates the list of URLs to scrape, then starts `scrape` for all of them.

  - Note that *all* 100 requests start at once; this may or may not be a problem for you.
- Finally, when all of the scrape promises complete, their return values are gathered into `response`, and that's written into the JSON file.

  - This differs from the original in that the original kept re-writing the file as new content was scraped.

```
async function scrape(url) {
  try {
    const htmlPage = await requestPromise(url);
    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlPage);
    const texts = [];
    $('.fixedttitle2').each(function () {
      texts.push($(this).text());
    });
    return [url, texts];
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error processing url: ${url}: ${err}`);
    return [url, null];
  }
}

async function main() {
  const urls = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    urls.push(`https://thisurl.com/${i}`);
  }
  const response = await Promise.all(urls.map(scrape));
  fs.writeFileSync('1.json', JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

If you'd like the requests to be done sequentially, you can `await scrape()` in the loop:

```
async function main() {
  const response = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    const url = `https://thisurl.com/${i}`;
    response.push(await scrape(url));
  }
  fs.writeFileSync('1.json', JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

You could also move the write file call into the loop if you wanted the same incremental behavior your original code had.

### EDIT

You can also add a delay to the sequential loop:

```
// Basic promisified delay function
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function main() {
  const response = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    const url = `https://thisurl.com/${i}`;
    response.push(await scrape(url));
    await delay(1000); // Wait for 1000 ms between scrapes
  }
  fs.writeFileSync('1.json', JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

Comment: very nice. very expert. really you are a perfect man in the coding. one remains challenge for me. I have a notation here "mainarray[urls[index]] = myarray;" in your code index is not defined. how I can maintain mainarray[urls[index]] property? i.e: not return in format "return [url, texts];"

Comment: If you need a `{url: ...}` object (_not_ an array!), then do `JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(response));` instead.

Comment: I'm sure you are the number one in programming.

Comment: I love this answer, every day I see it again. thanks.

Comment: one question: how I can add a 1 second delay between requests? is it simple?

Comment: @MaryamPanahi Sure thing, please see my edit.